# Marking rows of table as duplicate if one column has duplicate values

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a table `caller` which keeps track of all the calls I receive. The columns are `"phone" , "time" , and "ID"` which I then show on a web page. Now I want to show `(Repeat)` with phone numbers that have called twice or more. 
Right Now I am using the following query.

```
SELECT `Phone`, `Id`, `time` 
FROM callers
GROUP BY phone
ORDER BY `time` DESC
```

this query returns the phones only once which have called twice. I want to show those phones as many time as they have called. Just want a `(R)` written in front of every phone that has been repeated. 
I am using Codeigniter framework and PHP.

Example (What I want)

```
ID       Phone          Time
1        789654 (R)      3:40
2        789654 (R)      3:30
3        123456          2:00
4        012344          1:00
```

What the above query gives me

```
ID       Phone          Time
1        789654 (2)      3:40
2        123456          2:00
3        012344          1:00
```

Comment: ran this query. this gives me only those record that have called only once.

Comment: ...and what I have to begin with...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to calculate the information about repetition separately from listing the numbers.  Here is a method using `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT c.*, cc.RepeatFlag
FROM callers c LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT `Phone`, 'R' as RepeatFlag
      FROM callers
      GROUP BY phone
      HAVING cnt > 1
     ) cc
     ON cc.phone = c.phone
ORDER BY `time` DESC ;
```

This uses a bit of a trick.  The subquery only returns the the phones with duplicates.  For these, it sets the `RepeatFlag`.  For non-matches, this is `NULL`.  You can choose whatever columns you want from `callers` for the rest of the columns.

Answer (score 0):

This query will return no of calls per phone no.

```
 SELECT `Phone`, `Id`, `time`, count(Id) as no_of_calls 
 FROM callers
 GROUP BY phone
 ORDER BY `time` DESC
```

Or

```
 SELECT `Phone`, `Id`, `time`, IF(count(Id)>1, 1, 0) as repeat 
 FROM callers
 GROUP BY phone
 ORDER BY `time` DESC
```

Comment: did my answer helped you?

Comment: Same result as above :(.

Comment: But it would also have repeat tag or count for phone calls?

Comment: is there a way to mark the duplicate phone numbers without using GROUP BY? coz I think GROUP BY cannot help me here

Comment: Yes it gave me the exact count number of calls each person has made. But it grouped each number and showed it as one.

Comment: With query you cant but with php code you can. You have to write php script for that or you can also write a mysql procedure.

Comment: with current result you can write repeat with every result more than one while displaying.

Comment: please mark my answer as correct if my code helps you.

Comment: I am sorry Harish but your answer did not work. It gave me the same result as my own query. however i really appreciate u helping me :)